# How do I make the APA references appear with the numbering and without being overflowed?

Tags: apa-style

My codes are here below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{reference.bib}
\end{document}
```

For example, from the file "reference.bib", I have this code for Reference [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEFC7.png)

```
@misc{echinacities, title={2016 Provinces with the Largest Population: Guangdong Takes Crown}, url={http://www.echinacities.com/news/2016-Provinces-with-the-Largest-Population-Guangdong-Takes-Crown}, journal={eChinacities}}
```

but when I compiled it, the

[image: following image is shown below]

Instead of `\bibliographystyle{apa}`, I tried `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` but it didn't work. When I tried `\usepackage{apacite}` and 
`\bibliographystyle{apacite}`, I was able to generate the references in apa format but the numbering did not appeared. Also, some of the texts overflowed the page.

[image: When I tried \usepackage{apacite}\bibliographystyle{apacite}]

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399291/how-do-i-make-the-references-appear-in-apa-format-date-and-the-website-retreiev

Comment: Yes, I wasn't able to make a comment on the previous one.